# Hibernate StackOverflowError with @OneToMany and @ManyToOne mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

### Entities

I have three entities `User`, `Permission` and `UserPermission`.

```
[User] --(OneToMany)--> [UserPermission]
[UserPermission] --(ManyToOne)--> [User]
[UserPermission] --(ManyToOne)--> [Permission]
```

These are the simplified implementations:

```java
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
@NoArgsConstructor @RequiredArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @NonNull @NotNull
    private String id;

    // ... Other non pk fields

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Collection<UserPermission> permissions;
}
```

```java
@Entity @IdClass(UserPermission.PK.class)
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor @RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserPermission {
    @Id @NonNull @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private User user;

    @Id @NonNull @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "permission", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Permission permission;

    // ... Other non pk fields

    @Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class PK implements Serializable {
        private User user;

        private Permission permission;
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor @RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Permission {
    @Id
    @NonNull @NotNull
    private String id;

    // ... Other non pk fields
}
```

### The problem

When I try to update an `UserPermission` using the method `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.save(S)`:

```java
@Override
public T upd(ID id, T entity) {
    entity.setPk(id);
    return repository.save(entity);
}
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.lang.Character.isWhitespace(Character.java:6789) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Character.isWhitespace(Character.java:6757) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at org.postgresql.core.Parser.parseJdbcSql(Parser.java:82) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.CachedQueryCreateAction.create(CachedQueryCreateAction.java:63) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.CachedQueryCreateAction.create(CachedQueryCreateAction.java:17) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.util.LruCache.borrow(LruCache.java:115) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.QueryExecutorBase.borrowQuery(QueryExecutorBase.java:271) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.borrowQuery(PgConnection.java:146) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.<init>(PgPreparedStatement.java:78) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.prepareStatement(PgConnection.java:1223) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.prepareStatement(PgConnection.java:1681) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.prepareStatement(PgConnection.java:371) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar:42.2.5]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:311) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:172) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:148) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1984) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1914) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1892) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:937) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2281) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4269) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:511) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:481) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:222) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:92) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1257) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1140) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]

    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:682) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:688) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:862) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:718) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]

    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]

    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2281) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4269) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:511) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:481) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:222) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:92) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1257) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1140) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]


    // Repeated over and over

    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:682) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:688) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:862) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:718) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2281) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4269) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:511) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:481) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:222) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:92) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1257) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1140) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
```

### What I do know

I know for sure the problem lies in the "recursive" relation between `User` and `UserPermission`.

If I remove the mapping to `User` in `UserPermission` the exception goes away:

```java
public class UserPermission {
    @Id @NonNull @NotNull
    private String user;
```

### What I don't know

How can I map these two entities without getting this exception, it doesn't matter if the entities are not mapped perse I just want to enforce the relationship

#### Update 1

Adding the mappedBy attribute to the OneToMany annotation in the User entity and removing the JoinColumn annotation:

```java
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
private Collection<UserPermission> permissions;
```

Does not fix the problem but the stacktrace changed:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
    at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:161) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
    at io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.logging.MetricsTurboFilter.decide(LogbackMetrics.java:132) ~[micrometer-core-1.1.3.jar:1.1.3]
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.TurboFilterList.getTurboFilterChainDecision(TurboFilterList.java:49) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext.getTurboFilterChainDecision_0_3OrMore(LoggerContext.java:269) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.callTurboFilters(Logger.java:751) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
    at ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger.isTraceEnabled(Logger.java:623) ~[logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:na]
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger.isEnabledFor(SLF4JLogger.java:213) ~[log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JLogger.isEnabled(SLF4JLogger.java:121) ~[log4j-to-slf4j-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.isEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1504) ~[log4j-api-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at org.jboss.logging.Log4j2Logger.isEnabled(Log4j2Logger.java:46) ~[jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar:3.3.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.logging.Logger.isTraceEnabled(Logger.java:98) ~[jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar:3.3.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.logging.DelegatingBasicLogger.isTraceEnabled(DelegatingBasicLogger.java:54) ~[jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar:3.3.2.Final]

    // Repeated over and over   

    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4269) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:511) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:481) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:222) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:281) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:92) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1257) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:1140) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:682) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:464) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.resolve(ManyToOneType.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:457) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.resolve(ComponentType.java:688) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:862) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:718) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:310) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2281) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.7.Final.jar:5.3.7.Final]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to remove `@JoinColumn` from the parent entity (User) and use the mappedBy attribute with `@OneToMany` as suggested by [piyush-tyagi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9417714/piyush-tyagi):

```java
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
@NoArgsConstructor @RequiredArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
    @Id
    @NonNull @NotNull
    private String id;

    // ... Other non pk fields

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
    private Collection<UserPermission> permissions;
}
```

Use `@EmbeddedId` for the pk in the child entity (UserPermission):

```java
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler" })
@NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor @RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserPermission {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PK pk;

    @Embeddable
    @Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class PK implements Serializable {
        private String user;

        private String permission;
    }
}
```

And map the parent entities using `@MapsId`

```java
@MapsId("user")
@NonNull @NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private User user;

@MapsId("permission")
@NonNull @NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "permission", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private Permission permission;
```

Finally, implement the getters/setters so the fields are in sync:

```
@JsonIgnore
public PK getPk() {
    if (pk == null) {
        pk = new PK();
    }

    return pk;
}

public void setPk(PK pk) {
    this.pk = pk;
    this.user = new User(pk.getUser());
    this.permission = new Permission(pk.getPermission());
}

public User getUser() {
    if (user == null) {
        user = new User(getPk().getUser());
    }

    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
    getPk().setUser(user.getId());
}

public Permission getPermission() {
    if (permission == null) {
        permission = new Permission(getPk().getPermission());
    }

    return permission;
}

public void setPermission(Permission permission) {
    this.permission = permission;
    getPk().setPermission(permission.getId());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into similar issue, got rid of lombok annotations in entity class and that created getters and setters, this resolved the issue in my case.

Answer (score 0):

since you are having bidirectional relation in user class which is having one to many relatoon you should use @mappedby and not @joincolumn which I feel is causing the recursive process, leading to stackoverflow error

Comment: Do you mean at the User or UserPermission entity?

Comment: in user entity as you already have joincloumn in userpermission also it's best practice to make many to one entity as owner of relationship and not one to many so anytime you have such situations always use mappedby on onetomany and @joincolumn on manytoone

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I added mappedBy and removed JoinColumn but the problem persists (I edited the question).

Comment: Looking at the sql log from hibernate, it fetches the user permission, the permission and then the user over and over

Comment: It's because of the primary key having user as a field in it.

Comment: So, it is not possible to create a ManyToOne relationship if the column is part of the primary key, is it?

Comment: Its cyclic relationship that you have created that way as you are in turn calling userpermission from user, while everytime a new object is created it needs user object in its primary key so you either change your primary key or remove onetomany apart in user entity

Comment: I had the same problem with bidirectional relationships. But the problem wasn't the relationship itself. I used the @ToString annotation of the Lombok project for the String representation of my entity classes. Indeed, bidirectional references (A -> B, B -> A) produce cyclic method calls which ends in StackOverflowError. My solution was to override the toString() method to prevent recursive method calls.